# Resolve IP by DNS on local Network

Tags: apache-http-server, noip

i want to resolve my ip with specific DNS just for my local network is there any possibility to access my local hosted website with my local clients?

Comment: This would depend on your setup. You could always setup a local DNS and configure your clients to use it. Alternatively you might directly manipulate the hosts file. Which might be fine for a really, really small network.

Comment: `nslookup` in Windows does that. If you are on another OS, well, you should have mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this many ways, but here are 2.

1. for a single machine, you can edit the hosts file (windows/system32/drivers/etc). Open the hosts file with admin access and input the Domain name and IP you want to resolve, as per the examples, and on that machine, it will work.
2. Install a DNS Server, and configure it with the A record to the IP you want to resolve.